# Git strategies for a partially sharing a repo

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository which has multiple sub packages on our private git. There is a requirement to share some of the packages to public Github while keeping other ones internal only. Is there a good practice to:

1. Avoid dup our effort when we make changes on the public packages in the future? We do not want to do everything twice.
2. If we do not mirror our whole repository, just to set up multiple remotes, is it possible to ignore those internal only packages only for the public Github repo?
3. If we have to maintain 2 separated repos, is it possible to do quick cherry pick cross them?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share only part of a repository.  Git doesn't permit the separation of the contents of a repository.

If you want to share only some of those packages, you can add the private ones as submodules pointing to a private repository and share the main repository but not the submodules.  This is better than having two separate repositories, because the histories will likely differ completely and cherry-picking won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This link seems to provide a way share only selected subfolders on Github.  It doesn't mention the public vs private aspects of your question, but I imagine if you create the separate subset repo, you can use the Github configuration panel to see if you can make only that portion public.

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository